# How to pass the correct value when calling a method?

Tags: java, methods

I'm doing an assignment in which I have created an Appliance class that has a `timePasses()`method within it. This method re-directs some values that need to be stored within another method that is inside of another class. Here is where I am up to on this:

**Appliance**

```
public class ElectricCooker extends Cooker {

    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int incrementTime;
    public int varPass = -1;

    @Override
    public int currentState() {
        if (varPass == 0) {
            return isOff;
        } else {
            return isOn;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void useTime(int defaultTime) {
        defaultTime = 15;
        incrementTime = 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void timePasses() {
        if (varPass == isOff) {
            varPass = 0;
        } else {
            ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);
            GasMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(gasUse);
            WaterMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(waterUse);
        }
    }

    ElectricCooker(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn) {
        super(electricityUse, gasUse, waterUse, timeOn);

        this.electricityUse = 5 * incrementTime;
        this.gasUse = 0 * incrementTime;
        this.waterUse = 0 * incrementTime;
        this.timeOn = 15 * incrementTime;
    }
}
```

**Meter**

```
public class ElectricMeter {

    ElectricMeter() {
    }
    private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();

    public static ElectricMeter getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void incrementConsumed(int value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public int incrementGenerated() {
    }

    public boolean canGenerate() {
    }

    public String getConsumed() {
    }

    public String getGenerated() {
    }
}
```

**Main method**

```
public class MainCoursework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ElectricMeter a = new ElectricMeter();
        a.incrementConsumed(//what goes here?);     
    }
}
```

So the value from `timePasses()`has been redirected into an `ElectricMeter` instance but now I need to return that value to the `increentConsumed()` method in the meter class and I'm stuck on how to do this. Since the value of `electricityConsumed` is 20, the output should be `20`. But instead I have to pass a parameter into `a.incrementConsumed(//pass parameter here)` and what ever is passed gets printed out onto the screen instead of the `20` from `electrictyUse`. Any help on how to do this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the `incrementConsumed` method is indeed implemented as you described:

```
public void incrementConsumed(int value)  
{
    System.out.println(value);     
}
```

A method called `incrementXXX` shouldn't really output anything, should it? It should *increment* a variable/field:

```
private int electricityUsed = 0;
public void incrementConsumed(int value)  
{
    electricityUsed += value;    
}
```

You should declare another method that returns `electricityUsed`:

```
public int getElectricityUsed() {
    return electricityUsed;
}
```

Now let's fix your `main` method.

In your main method, you didn't even create anything that consumes electricity! How can the electric meter `incrementConsumed`? So remove everything from the main method and create a cooker:

```
// your constructor looks weird. So I passed in some random arguments..
ElectricCooker cooker = new ElectricCooker(20, 0, 0, 60);
```

Now call `timePasses` to simulate that some time passed:

```
cooker.timePasses();
```

And print the electricity used:

```
System.out.println(ElectricMeter.getInstance().getElectricityUsed());
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create an instance variable in `ElectricMeter` and update that value on say `incrementConsumed`. When you want to print that use `accessor` of this variable.

```
public class Electric {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ElectricCooker cooker = new ElectricCooker(1,2,3,4);
        //opertion on cooker
        //ignoring best way for singleton creation
        int electricityUse = ElectricMeter.getInstance().getElectricityUse();
        System.out.println(electricityUse);
    }
}

class ElectricCooker // extends Cooker
{
    public int isOn = -1;
    public int isOff = 0;
    public int incrementTime;
    public int varPass = -1;
    public int electricityUse = -1;

    public int currentState() {
        if (varPass == 0)
            return isOff;
        else {
            return isOn;
        }
    }

    public void useTime(int defaultTime) {
        defaultTime = 15;
        incrementTime = 4;
    }

    public void timePasses() {
        if (varPass == isOff)
            varPass = 0;
        else {
            ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);
        }
    }

    ElectricCooker(int electricityUse, int gasUse, int waterUse, int timeOn) {
        this.electricityUse = 5 * incrementTime;
    }

}

class ElectricMeter {

    public int electricityUse = -1;

    private static ElectricMeter instance = new ElectricMeter();

    public static ElectricMeter getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void incrementConsumed(int value) {
        this.electricityUse = value;
    }

    public int getElectricityUse() {
        return electricityUse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ElectricMeter`, some operations don't perform what they should.

```
  ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(electricityUse);
```

should increment something but it writes only in the output:

```
public void incrementConsumed(int value){
         System.out.println(value);     
    }
```

You should write it rather :

```
public void incrementConsumed(int value){
           consumed+=value; 
    }
```

and add a `private int consumed` field in `ElectricMeter` class to store the actual consumed.

And your `getConsumed()` which has a empty implementation :

```
public String getConsumed(){

}
```

should simply return the `consumed` field and you should return a `int` value and not a `String`.

```
public int getConsumed()  {
  return consumed;
}
```

In this way, you can do :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  ElectricMeter.getInstance().incrementConsumed(20);     
  int consumed = ElectricMeter.getInstance().getConsumed();     
}
```